# How To Fix Icon For InstallShield

Tags: c#, installshield

I used to be able to create a setup project in Visual Studio, but now Microsoft has "improved" it and I'm wasting hours trying to get a simple project to someone else in my company.  They need to upgrade their version of .NET or I wouldn't even use a setup.  So after going through the pain of downloading their "improved" InstallShield and going through the pain of watching a video and setting all the parameters I tried to build the Setup project and it says the icon isn't valid.  "Screw the icon.  Let me deploy my project."  The actual error message is "Cannot extract icon with index 0 from file ..."  It doesn't matter to me if this uses a standard icon or no icon, I just want the user to be able to test this project.

So, what is the easiest way to get this setup project in the hands of my user?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to create an installer when you can just do clickonce? Or have them download the .NET framework installer?

Comment: I don't know how to do those.  My supervisor suggested that I create a Setup project and it seemed like a good idea to me.

Comment: The Visual Studio Setup Project is still available as VS Extension:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d. It's available for VS 2013 and 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a new icon to the project and re-compiling.  You can do this by right-clicking on the project and selecting Add -> New Item -> Icon File.  Then assign that icon file under the Project -> Properties menu item.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution:**

> At the time of Installation Wizard, while missing the reselection of
>   the Image / Icon for shortcut after we have browsed the resource path.
>   Missing this causes this index error (please refer screenshot). after
>   re-selection rebuild is required this solves problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to fix this error :
Right click on your project- go to properties-application tab-in application tab set icon to your project in Icon & Manifest option